# Validate empty string in form

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms

I have a form that takes the users input and concatenated that to a url (written in function). How do I check to see if the users value is empty and have an alert appear right below the form that says "Please enter a valid store URL". With out having to re write my entire function! Help!

Input form

```
<form id="url">
        <input type="text" name="urlName">
        <button onclick="return myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </form>
```

Javscript Function

```
document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
    
    function myFunction() {
            let myForm = document.getElementById("url");
            let formData = new FormData(myForm);
            EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
            newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
            window.location.href = newUrl;
            return false;
        }


    function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
        input = input || 'unknown.com'
        if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
            input = input.substr(7)
        }
        if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
            input = input.substr(8)
        }

        var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
        return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com';     
    }
    

    function redirectLink(domain) {
        return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`;
    }
```

Check empty string I have not working

```
 function valInput() {
        if (input.value.length === 0){
            alert("need valid store URL")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add more detail about the problem.  What result are you currently getting that isn't correct?  In other words, what's wrong?

Comment: Ok, the input form currently accepts a value and re directs them to a URL. That works great. I need to add a condition in there that checks if the form input is empty then a text appears below the form that alerts them to "add url can't leave empty" but not sure how to add it in my current function without completely re writing

Comment: I know what you want to achieve and I know what you did wrong. Check my answer, is that what you wanted?

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I am now trying to figure out how to show the error message inline and below the input field. I got as far as innerHTML but am now stuck. Also I am writing this in wordpress raw html.

Comment: If you use a required attribute on your input, the web browser will handle the validation.

Comment: For some reason wordpress doesnt allow this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `myFunction` you can simple add this code after creating a new instance of `FormData`:

```js
if (formData.get("urlName") === "")
    return alert('asdsa')
```

It will stop the whole function because of `return` and will alert you that you haven't put anything in the input box.

**Actually, the whole code is kinda wrong**

Here's the correct version of javascript code:

```js
document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let myForm = document.getElementById("url");
    let formData = new FormData(myForm);
    if (formData.get("urlName").length === 0)
        return alert('Provide valid url')
    EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
    newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
    window.location.href = newUrl;
    return false;
});



function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
    input = input || 'unknown.com'
    if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
        input = input.substr(7)
    }
    if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
        input = input.substr(8)
    }

    var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
    return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com';     
}


function redirectLink(domain) {
    return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`;
}
```

You call the `myFunction` twice and you don't even prevenDefault from sending form, so the form is sent whatever you do in the `myFunction`.

And in HTML you don't need button. You can add `input:submit` which will trigger function onclick automatically. Here's the correct html code:

```html
<form id="url">
    <input type="text" name="urlName">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I am now trying to figure out how to show the  error message inline and below the input field. I got as far as innerHTML but am now stuck    
 if (formData.get("urlName").length === 0)
                    return document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = 'Provide valid url';

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. Anyway, you should create HTML tag in your HTML file with id and then put information about invalid url using `innerText` or `innerHTML` as you mentioned. You're on a good way. By the way, if my answer helped you, could you sign it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [onBlur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) handler to the input.

```js
function validate(val) {
  if(val.trim() === "") {
    alert("Field is required");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="urlName" onblur="validate(this.value)">
```

Comment: What if the user doesn’t focus on the input field before submitting the form?